# Several inserts performance c#

Tags: c#, database

I´ve to do several inserts into one table. Now, I´ve a list of objects that i iterate, and for each object i do an ExecuteNonQuery with the insert statement.

I want to know if there are a faste way to do this.
In this way, inserting 800 registers takes a couple of minutes.

I´ve used in Java the executeBatch method, who is for this propose, is there anything similar in c#.

Regards !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Inserts* are [relatively] fast/cheap. *Commits* are slow/expensive.

Unless it is a *high* latency connection, multiple (as in, hundreds of) insert statements should be just fine.

"...takes a couple minutes..." sounds like transactions are not being used (and thus there are likely 800 commits -- ouch!). One of the easiest ways to control transactions in C# is to use a [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx):

```
using (var connection = ...)
using (var tx = new TransactionScope()) {
   foreach (var row in rows) {
      // insert row
   }
   // commit all at once
   tx.Complete();
}
```

I would only consider approaches if limiting the number of transactions (and thus commits) is not sufficient to meet functional requirements.

Happy coding.

Comment: I´m already using the transaction scope (at business layer), so i think there is only one commit when tx.Complete()

Comment: @Rodrigo Just verify it is really being used -- 800 commits in a couple minutes is *really slow*. I can't imagine that even over-indexing and/or bad fragmentation would lead to that (but I've been surprised by more ;-). Also verify that the latency to the server is acceptable; a [high] latency will be the issue that limits the speed of individual commands. (A 50ms latency will reduce the maximum separate commands/second to about 20; and thus might be a very good candidate to send less individual commands. Include this information in the post if relevant.)

Comment: I´m trying the process over a VPN throught Internet, so maybe is the problem. How can i check the latency

Answer (score 1):

Your statement could be something like this:

```
insert into my_table (field1, field2, ...)
values (row1_value1, row2_value2, ...),
       (row2_value1, row2_value2, ...), ...
```

So if you create for example a StringBuilder, you could batch up 20, 50 or 100 inserts and issue much less insert statements.

Comment: Yes, it is a way, i just think that i could be a nicer way to do this. Just a question, do you add the values concatenating strings? or adding parameters to the command with dynamic names?

Comment: I try to add parameters to the commands but i have an exception cause i exceded the parameters limit (2100?). How can i do ?

Comment: @Rodrigo: How many columns are you inserting? In other words, if you divide 2100 by the number of columns, can you still batch a significant number of rows? If so, stick to that limit. If not, format the strings yourself (don't forget to escape special characters like quotes!!)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Performing Batch Operations Using DataAdapters (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aadf8fk2.aspx) if you want to do everything from your .NET app.

If you want the fastest possible performance you could use the [bcp utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) (assuming you're using SQL Server.) You would write your data to a delimited file and use bcp to perform the inserts.

Answer (score 0):

What about writting all your insert statement in a string separated by ';' and pass this string to ExecuteNonQuery ?

to check for error just compare the number of insert with the row affected that ExecuteNonQuery  return

Comment: You can also to create a stored procedure which receives an XML parameter